# How send data to php file With Post

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and I want to send data(id in my program) to a php file and get it with $_POST ,and then send the result back but the Solution's that i have found didn't work .

I think my body is wrong , I tried to change body to a

```
Map<String,dynamic>
```

but its didn't work.

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
  String body = "{'id' : 1}" ;
  String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/facts/get.php";
  http.Response responseData = await http.post(
  url
 ,body: body);
  print(responseData.body);
  return json.decode(responseData.body);
}
```

Comment: Please post php code

Comment: $id_in_program = $_POST["id"];   I have this line in my php file

Comment: No no. First try to print everything you are getting on post so that you wil be able to see what are you getting